# Change a section of the page on click in Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

My page is divided in two sections.
One section has drop downs and a submit button, and the other section is initially empty.

I want to do the following.
On click of submit button, I need to render the other section of the page with some content. For the sake of simplicity, say I need to display all the choices selected by the user in the drop down.

So I want the drop downs selected value to stay intact, but render content to the other section of the page, without refreshing/redirecting the page

Is this doable in laravel via controller?

I tried doing this via `echo` in my Controller however it did not work.

Comment: You would need to make use of vue.js as PHP is backend.

Answer (score 0):

You can call your controller or specific method using **AJAX** and return data to render second Section.